# How to Focus an Element in a WPF TreeView If Elements Come From ItemSource?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I can also paraphrase the question and ask how I can get a `TreeViewItem` out of a Model object in `TreeView.Items`?

I follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) and instead of `TreeViewItems` in the `TreeView.Items` collection I have objects of that model class.

However, I need to focus certain `TreeView` elements based on some other event. If `TreeView.Items` contained `TreeViewItems` I'd easily found a needed one and used its `Focus()` method. But since I'm using binding now I don't know how to do that.

Of course, I can populate a `TreeView` programmatically by adding `TreeViewItems` objects, however I tried to avoid it and follow a more WPF-way of doing things with binding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
TreeViewItem tvItem = (TreeViewItem)treeView
                          .ItemContainerGenerator
                          .ContainerFromItem(item);
tvItem.Focus();
```

Comment: Thanks! The only thing you have to cast it to TreeViewItem

Comment: Be aware, container may be null in case of virtulization

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelectedInEditor, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  </Style>
```

This is my style for a TreeViewItem where i bound the IsSelected property to the Model object's IsSelectedInEditor property. Maybe it's not the best way to do this, but i found it easier than other solutions and it's worked out of the box. So after this setup you just need to find your object in the TreeView.Items and set its IsSelectedInEditor(or whatever name you choose) property to true.

Comment: This controls the "selection" but not the "focus". There is no bindable property for the focus. If you click in the tree, then programmatically select another item with this binding, the item you clicked still has a light border around it showing that it remains focused.

Comment: @SimonF I can't check my code's validity now, but maybe it worked in '11, but now after several wpf updates may be not.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem`

Find a post here : http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=7

And a small sample on how to use it :

XAML

```
<TreeView x:Name="tv" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataList}" SelectedItemChanged="tv_SelectedItemChanged">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BusinessProperty}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

code behind :

```
private void tv_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    var tvItem = tv.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(((TreeView)sender).SelectedItem);
}
```

and then do whatever you want with your treeview item :)